# Using i18n for ASP.NET on mobile device browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization

I have been trying to figure out this bizarre problem I am having when using the i18n library in my ASP.NET project running on mobile devices browsers. Localization works on desktop computers, I am able to switch languages, for example, my default language is "fr" and I can choose to change to "en" without any problems on a desktop.

/fr -> will show "fr" on a desktop browser
/en -> will show "en"on desktop browser

The problem is when I try to access the website on a mobile device browser. I will always get the "fr" language regardless of changing to "en"

/fr -> will show "fr" on mobile browsers
/en -> will show "fr" on mobile browsers

No matter what I do, I will always see the FR language only. The URL does changes BUT the translation doesn't happen. Below is the code I use in my global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Blacklist certain URLs from being 'localized'.
            i18n.UrlLocalizer.QuickUrlExclusionFilter = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"((sitemap\.xml|\.css|\.less|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.ico|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.eot)$)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Change from the default of 'en'.
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.DefaultLanguage = "fr";

        // Change from the of temporary redirects during URL localization
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.PermanentRedirects = true;

i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.SetPrincipalAppLanguageForRequestHandlers = delegate (System.Web.HttpContextBase context, ILanguageTag langtag)
            {
                // Do own stuff with the language tag.
                // The default handler does the following:
                if (langtag != null)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = langtag.GetCultureInfo();
                }
            };

    }
```

My web.config has the following:

```
<add key="i18n.DirectoriesToScan" value="..;web" />
    <add key="i18n.AvailableLanguages" value="fr;en;" />
    <add key="i18n.DefaultLanguage" value="fr" />
    <add key="i18n.WhiteList" value="*.aspx;*.ascx;*.cs;*.cshtml;*.sitemap;*.Master;*.master;" />
    <add key="i18n.BlackList" value=".\assets;.\bower_components;.\obj;" />
    <add key="i18n.VisualizeMessages" value="false" />
    <add key="i18n.NuggetVisualizeToken" value="!" />
```

and I have a simple dropdownlist to switch URL's from /fr to /en and vice versa.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Desktop browsers works fine, Mobile browsers doesn't, thank you so much.

Comment: What is the mobile browser? On iPhone I can find there is a setting about website using the 1st language in the available language list.

Comment: H @kennyzx, thanks for your message, alll browsers, this problem is not isolated to a particular browser or OS. I have the same problem using iPhone, Android or Windows phone. Basically, I suppose I must be doing something obvious really wrong because it doesn't make sense the end-user needs to modify a setting on the client to be able to get the localization working. I think this problem has nothing to do with the client, it has to do with the server side code (i18n).

Comment: Does anyone had a similar experience using i18n on mobile browsers and is there any alternative component to i18n that also uses PO files that I could switch to? Thanks a lot